# Java API Example for abstract class. unable to understand the concept properly so reposted

Tags: abstract-class, java

I am just trying myself to be comfortable with java api. But I am unable to do it. Not knowing the purpose of when to use abstract class.

Consider the java library collections

```
                          Collections

            List                                Set
```

All 3 are interfaces but the major thing , though they have functions which are common that is add , addAll, contains,containsAll etc. List implements in its own and set implements in another way ( telling about duplication ). Set does not allow duplicates list allows duplicates.

So what I am trying to say is  when ever there is no common features for sub-entity with super-entity we have to go for interface

To still more make it clear , if suppose we make Collection as abstract class we need some methods to be properly defined rather than just declared but the functionality of list and set is differnt ( no common definition to bothe) hence they just declared it as interface and made a force rule that both list and set should implement this.

But if there is some common functionality which both has then keep it as to be abstract class.

So to get an example from Java itself. Lets consider Number class which is made ABSTRACT. Lets see why it could not be done using interface now!!!

```
**public abstract class Number
extends Object
methods are**
```

**`byte    byteValue()`** 
          Returns the value of the specified number as a byte.

**`abstract double  doubleValue()`** 
          Returns the value of the specified number as a double.

**`abstract float   floatValue()`** 
          Returns the value of the specified number as a float.

**`abstract int intValue()`** 
          Returns the value of the specified number as an int.

**`abstract long    longValue()`** 
          Returns the value of the specified number as a long.

**`short    shortValue()`** 
          Returns the value of the specified number as a short.

Now here the byteValue is a non-abstract method and other methods XXXValue are abstract. We will see Y???

byteValue()

```
// taken from Number class java doc api

public byte byteValue()
```

Returns the value of the specified number as a byte. This may involve rounding or truncation.

```
And this byteValue() method is being overriden by all the other classes like Integer,Double,Float etc.
```

Instead they can keep byteValue() also abstract !!! But they dint do it. Wish to know why they have done like this.

Comment: Not even the mighty gods of software development that are the builders of the Java API are infallible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byteValue()` is **not** overridden in all the Number subclasses. For example, it's not in BigInteger, AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal. All those classes benefit from the default implementation in the Number class.

Comment: why could not they keep it as abstract ?  May I know the purpose Why cant these Classes that you mentioned can override it ?

Comment: why did other classes such as Integer Long float overridden  it

Comment: If they had made it abstract, all those classes above would have been forced to implement the method, and to duplicate the same implementation. By implementing it in the base class, the default implementation is not duplicated, and can be used by every subclass. I guess the overrode it in Integer, Long, etc. for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

An interface could not provide a default functionality for `byteValue()` and `shortValue()`. In this case, the default behavior is that calling each of these methods is the same as to calling `intValue()` with a proper cast.

Also, considering `Number` is not `final`, someone else could be extending it in their own codebase, and effectively inheriting the behavior of those methods.

Putting it (very) simply, if you only want to specify method signatures (i.e. all methods are `abstract`), you could (and probably should) define an interface.